# Add TSA signature to a existing PDF using iText

Tags: itext, trusted-timestamp

When I use Adobe Reader I can open a PDF (without any signature) and have it timestamped and signed by a TSA provider. I'm not signing the PDF myself with a TSA timestamp, it is actually the TSA provider the one that is singing and timestamping the PDF.

How can I do the same with iText?

Comment: Do you mean a *document time stamp*?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When I do it on Adobe Acrobat, the document appears as signed and timestampted by the TSA, and that's what I would like to do with iText

Comment: This is explained in the free ebook [Digital Signatures for PDF](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures)

Comment: *the document appears as signed and timestampted by the TSA* - do you really mean two distinct actions, *signing* and *time stamping*? I actually would be surprised if the TSA *signed* the document... (Ok, technologically creating a time stamp is like signing a special data structure,but the semantics differ considerably, so one should not mix up these terms.)